# Folders missing in sidebar with Big Sur

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur, sidebar

Since I installed macOS Big Sur 11.1, I cannot see the usual folders in the left sidebar of Finder:

[image]

even though I have selected them in my preferences:

[image]

What is going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you _mouse-over_ **Favorites** in the **Sidebar** of **Finder** and you do not see the right facing arrow **>**, then I'd start by deleting its _preferences file_, with the following _compound command_ in **Terminal** `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist; killall Finder` Note that this should reset to the defaults, but if it doesn't you'll need to delete it from **macOS Recovery**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next to "Favorites", if you hover over it, you should see an arrow you can click to expand the section. It must've been inadvertently clicked, since it's not new to Big Sur.

Comment: RE: "since it's not new to Big Sur." -- Actually the _arrow_ is  new to **macOS Big Sur**, because in prior versions of **macOS** when you _mouse-over_ **Sidebar**  category labels in **Finder**, it shows either **Hide/Show** depending on its current state.